# Display only records if the value in the last column ends with a 4

Tags: sed

Display only those records in a file if the value in the last column ends with a 4.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed -n '/4$/p' file.txt
```

`/4$/` matches `4` at the end of the line i.e. at the end of the last column.